# Character input being completely ignored in C

Tags: c

I am building a golf score board program and I need a single character input from the user asking if they are playing in a tournament. However when it comes to getting the single character input, it is completely ignored and the program quits. This is something that is tearing my hair out.

I've tried using different types of input like fgetc, getchar and scanf but all of these haven't worked.

```
void init(){
    char tournamentOrNot;
    char letter;
    char name[40];
    char golfClub[40];
    char tournament[60];
    printf("\nWhat is your name? ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin); //Input works
    getchar();
    printf("%s", name);
    printf("Where are you playing golf at? NO SPACES\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin); //Input works
    getchar();
    printf("Are you competing in a tournament?(Y/N)");
    tournamentOrNot = getchar(); //Input ignored and program exits
    if (tournamentOrNot == 'Y' || tournamentOrNot == 'y'){
        printf("\nEnter the name for the tournament NO SPACES: ");
        scanf("%s", &tournament);
        printf("Initializing score board...");
        printf("\n");
        drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament);
    }
    else if (tournamentOrNot == 'N' || tournamentOrNot == 'n'){
        tournament[7] = "Practice";
        printf("Initializing score board...");
        printf("\n");
        drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament);
    }
}
```

Current results:

```
What is your name? <input>
Where are you playing golf at?
<input>
Are you playing in a tournament or not? (Y/N)
<input ignored>

Program exited with code 0 Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: This `tournament[7] = "Practice";` is wrong. use `strcpy()` here.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Also here `printf("Are you competing in a tournament?(Y/N)");` why don't flush `stdout` buffer ? Either use `\n` or `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @42LeapsOfFaith No. `getchar()` does wait for user input.

Comment: What's the extra `getchar` doing after `fgets` and before `printf`?

Comment: @SteveSummit getchar() for some reason doesn't get name input ignored.

Comment: Well, we're going to have to figure that out.  When you have a program that doesn't work "for some reason" that you don't understand, and you insert random lines to try to fix it, things tend to get worse.

Comment: @fstanis what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Why don't you try `char tournamentOrNot[10];`, and then `fgets(tournamentOrNot, 10, stdin);` to read the y/n answer, and then `if (tournamentOrNot[0] == 'Y' || tournamentOrNot[0] == 'y')` to test it.

Comment: @SteveSummit No, the input is still being ignored/won't detect the input required.

Comment: Why read into `fgets(name,....` twice?

Comment: If you write `getchar()` and ignore the result, why are you surprised that the result of `getchar` is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, there are lots of ways of reading input in C, and it can be confusing to keep track of how they all work.  And in particular, there are some crazy interactions that tend to happen if you mix different ways of reading input in the same program.

Most of the time, you'll get the best results if you use `fgets` to read everything.  As you know, `fgets` reads *lines* of text.  If you wanted something else -- a number, or a single character, or whatever -- the thing to do is to then process that line of text (that `fgets` just read for you) a bit further, to extract the information you want.

So with that said, here's your `init` function rewritten to use only `fgets`:

```
void init(){
    char tournamentOrNot[10];
    char name[40];
    char golfClub[40];
    char tournament[60];
    printf("\nWhat is your name? "); fflush(stdout);
    fgets(name, 40, stdin);
    printf("Where are you playing golf at? "); fflush(stdout);
    fgets(golfClub, 40, stdin);
    printf("Are you competing in a tournament?(Y/N)"); fflush(stdout);
    fgets(tournamentOrNot, 10, stdin);
    if (tournamentOrNot[0] == 'Y' || tournamentOrNot[0] == 'y'){
        printf("Enter the name for the tournament: "); fflush(stdout);
        fgets(tournament, 60, stdin);
        printf("Initializing score board...\n");
        drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament);
    }
    else if (tournamentOrNot[0] == 'N' || tournamentOrNot[0] == 'n'){
        strcpy(tournament, "Practice");
        printf("Initializing score board...\n");
        drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament);
    }
}
```

The big change I made was to redeclare `tournamentOrNot` as an array of 10 characters, instead of a single `char`.  So we're actually reading a one-*line* response to the question "Are you competing in a tournament?". In this case, extracting the information we're interested (the one-character response) is easy: the first character of the array is `tournamentOrNot[0]`.

This seems strange at first: why treat `tournamentOrNot` as a string?  You wanted a Y/N answer, so obviously you declared `tournamentOrNot` as a `char`, and tried to use `getchar` to read it.  But as I said, it's tricky to mix things, and a mixture of `fgets` and `getchar` (and, further down, `scanf`) is very hard to get right.  So if we want to read all our input using `fscanf`, we need `tournamentOrNot` to be a string also, even though we expect the user to type a one-character string  like "Y" or "N".  (But this way it will also work if the user disobeys the instructions, and types "Yes" or "no".)

I also made some other changes:

- I added `fflush(stdout)` after the prompts, to make sure they come out.  (Prompts that don't end in `\n` sometimes don't show up right away unless you flush the output.)
- I got rid of the "NO SPACES" wording, because once we fix the inputs there shouldn't be problems with inputs with spaces in them.
- I used `fgets` to read the tournament name, too, because the problems with mixing input styles get even worse if you throw `scanf` into the mix.
- I changed `tournament[7] = "Practice"` to `strcpy(tournament, "Practice")`.
- I changed one instance of `fgets(name, 100, stdin)` to `fgets(name, 40, stdin)`.  (As @chux points out in a comment, eventually you'll want to learn a more reliable way of tracking these sizes, so you don't have to laboriously keep them matched up by hand.)
- I changed the other instance of `fgets(name, 100, stdin)` to `fgets(golfClub, 40, stdin)`; that may be behind your comment elsewhere that "the golf club question is being ignored".

Now, although I've just recommended using `fgets` to read all your input, there's one drawback to it that you're about to discover.  It leaves the terminating `\n` character in the line of text it reads.  Often you want to get rid of that.  One way to strip it off, although it's mildly cumbersome, is to say things like

```
char *p;
fgets(name, 100, stdin);
if((p = strrchr(name, '\n')) != NULL) *p = '\0';
```

And there are plenty of other ways, with various tradeoffs between compactness and convenience and correctness.

---

Finally, if you're curious, here's some more explanation about the "crazy interactions that can happen if you mix different ways of reading input in the same program".  The problem basically has to do with: newlines (`\n`) and other whitespace.  Some input methods read the newline and give it back to you, some read the newline but don't give it back to you, some leave the newline on the input stream (which means that a later input call will find it).  Some input methods skip other whitespace, some don't.  (And in the case of `scanf`, some of its input directives skip whitespace and others don't.)

If you really want to, you can learn and keep track of all these seemingly-inconsequential differences, and write a program that uses a mixture `fgets`, `getchar`, and `scanf`, but actually works.  Personally, though, I find this is far more trouble than it's worth, so I prefer to either use `fgets` (or some other line-reading function) everywhere, or use `getchar` everywhere.  (And I never use `scanf`.)

Comment: `char name[40]; ... fgets(name, 100, stdin);` is prone to failure.  suggest `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);` idiom.

Comment: `strtok(buffer, "\n");` fails to remove the `'\n'` when buffer is `"\n"`.   Consider `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: @chux: wrt `strtok`: Thanks.  That's not a technique I use -- I noticed it in another SO answer and thought it was cute -- and I didn't realize it had that limitation.  wrt `sizeof`: sure.  But sometimes we have to take one small step at a time...

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with the program function. I presume you do not want the newlines appearing in the strings, so they must be removed.
When using `fgets` the buffer size must be less or equal to the string size, otherwise you risk issues.
More in the commented program code below.

```
void init()
{
  char tournamentOrNot;
  char letter;
  char name[100]; // <-- make name 100 char long
  char golfClub[40];
  char tournament[60];

  printf("What is your name? ");
  fgets(name, 100, stdin); //Input works <-- buffer same as name
  // begin remove newline
  int index = 0;
  while (name[index] != '\n')
    index++;
  name[index] = '\0';
  // end remove new line
  // getchar(); <-- Not needed I think
  printf("%s\n", name);

  printf("Where are you playing golf at? NO SPACES\n");
  fgets(name, 100, stdin); //Input works <-- buffer same as name
  // begin remove newline
  index = 0;
  while (name[index] != '\n')
    index++;
  name[index] = '\0';
  // end remove newline
  // getchar(); <-- Not needed I think

  printf("Are you competing in a tournament? (Y/N) ");
  tournamentOrNot = getchar();

  if (tournamentOrNot == 'Y' || tournamentOrNot == 'y')
  {
    printf("Enter the name for the tournament NO SPACES: ");
    scanf("%s", tournament); // <-- tournament instead of &tournament
    printf("Initializing score board...");
    printf("\n");
    //drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament); <-- does this function know the sizes of the strings ?
    printf("socre board is drawn here\n");
  }
  else if (tournamentOrNot == 'N' || tournamentOrNot == 'n')
  {
    //tournament[7] = "Practice"; <-- that is wrong in C
    strcpy(tournament, "Practice"); // <-- string copied with strcpy
    printf("Initializing score board...");
    printf("\n");
    // drawScoreBoard(name, golfClub, tournament); <-- does this function know the sized of the strings ?
    printf("socre board is drawn here\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: `while (name[index] != '\n')
    index++;` runs off the end of `name[]` should not have a `\n` (long line).  Alternative `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: @Ely This is a good answer, however, the golfClub question is being ignored, any way to fix this. This is currently the output: What is your name?Where are you playing golf at?<input being taken as name>

Comment: @HarveyGray I am not sure what the issue is. I used it that function in a sample code and looked fine to me. Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

There are three potential issues that I see:

```
fgets(name, 100, stdin);
```

If the line is longer than 100 characters, this will only read part of it. You should write a separate function that continues to read until it sees newline or EOF, reallocing the buffer as needed.

```
printf("Are you competing in a tournament?(Y/N)");
tournamentOrNot = getchar(); //Input ignored and program exits
```

The operating system doesn't necessarily send all input to the program as soon as a key is pressed. It's more efficient to buffer input and then send it in a single chunk, usually by waiting until it sees a newline (or EOF) and sending the whole line at once.  Since this is operating system dependent, the fix will vary between systems.  In Unix, the ncurses library is used to give more direct control of I/O, including disabling line buffering. I believe there's a clone of this library in Windows called pdcurses. Below is an example of a basic ncurses program that prints input characters as soon as the key is pressed.  Further information can be found in the [ncurses HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int c;
    initscr();//initialization
    cbreak();//no line buffering
    noecho();//when you type a character, it doesn't show up on screen

    //getch is like getchar, but it reads immediately in cbreak mode
    while ('q' != (c = getch())) {
        //Note that we're explicitly sending both line feed
        //and carriage return here; curses allows you to
        //do one without the other.
        printf("%c (%02x)\n\r", c, c);
    }
    endwin();//cleanup
}
```

Finally, an issue that isn't *quite* present in your program, but could become an issue if a few things were done differently: if an input function doesn't consume the newline character at the end of a line, it will still be in the buffer, and will be the first character read by the next input function.  So, for instance, suppose the input is "42\nfoo\n", and you run the following code:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

scanf will read 42 into n, but not the '\n'. fgets will then read the newline, and immediately stop before getting to "foo", which is probably not what was intended. In this particular example, the best solution is generally to read the entire line, then use sscanf to parse it. But the general solution is just to always be aware of what is going to be left in the buffer after each statement.